# Mysql row number with order by very slow

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel

I have this query

```
select courses.id, y.qs_world, courses.name_en as name, 
courses.description_en as description,
source_link, courses.slug, fee, duration, courses.university_id, college_id,
study_level_id, application_fee, courses.currency_id 
from courses
left join university_ranks as y on courses.university_id = y.university_id
and y.year = '2021' 
left join universities on courses.university_id = universities.id
left join countries on countries.id = universities.country_id where courses.status = 1

order by ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY countries.id ORDER BY courses.id)
```

This query is taking too long to execute, but it is working well if I remove the last row.

I used indexing but nothing different.

The `EXPLAIN` notes are to `Using temporary,Using filesort` but I want to improve the query without using `temporary` or `filesort`

How can I achieve this?

**UPDATE**:
I tried this query but same speed

```
SELECT * FROM (    
     SELECT
      `courses`.`id`,`courses`.`status`,  `y`.`qs_world`, `courses`.`name_en` as `name`, `courses`.`description_en` as `description`,
 `source_link`, `courses`.`slug`, `fee`, `duration`, `courses`.`university_id`, `college_id`,
 `study_level_id`, `application_fee`, `courses`.`currency_id`, `countries`.`id` as country_id
    FROM
      courses
      left join `university_ranks` as `y` on `courses`.`university_id` = `y`.`university_id`
 and `y`.`year` = '2021'
 left join `universities` on `courses`.`university_id` = `universities`.`id`
 left join `countries` on `countries`.`id` = `universities`.`country_id`
 
) UserCourse  where status = 1
order by ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY country_id ORDER BY id)
```

Comment: There are two things that stand out when I see this: (1) the `WHERE status = 1` is in the wrong spot. It should be part of the main query, otherwise you're wasting a lot of time joining data for courses where the status is not `1` / (2) There is no need to wrap the main query in another query. This just adds needless complexity.

Comment: But the problem is in `order by` if I remove it everything will be ok

Comment: If you need all the records for the same country to be grouped together, you can just `order by country_id, id`. As long as there just IDs in the row_number, it looks like there's no any other specific logic here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- `countries`.`id` as country_id --> `universities`.`country_id`
- then remove

  ```
    left join  `countries`  ON `countries`.`id` = `universities`.`country_id`
  ```
- Move `where  status = 1` into the inner query.
- It seems like

  ```
     order by  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY country_id ORDER BY  id)
  ```

  could be replaced by

  ```
     ORDER BY country_id, id
  ```
- Get rid of the outer query
- Don't say `LEFT` unless the 'right' table might have a missing row.  (It confuses the reader as to your intent.)

Comment: `ORDER BY country_id, id` won't work like what I need, cuz I need to sort every row with different country  than the next row

Comment: @Decoder - Please provide a short set of data plus the desired results.

Comment: after removing left join 'countries' everything works good